# how to use ajax to post data on to the php page & then write the content to xml file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i want to pass the data returned by a javascript function  and the file name to a php page using ajax
and then write that data in a file i.e takinf the file name from ajax post appending that name with .xml and finally writing that data to xml file.

Comment: Are you trying to write the XML file on the client or server?

Answer (score 0):

For Posting use jquery [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("myxmlpage.php",  //your url
    { "data1": "data1value", "data2": "data2value"}, //data values
    function(data){ //Your onsuccess call backfunction
        alert(data.name); 
        console.log(data.time); 
    }, "json" //retun data type //can be html/json/xml/text
    );
```

For writing to xml file. check this [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=14165),